Latest version of helm building on python 3.8
I am currently in the processing of moving our airflow instances to a K8 cluster. I have been installed the latest version of the helm chart (1.13.1), which gives airflow 2.8.3. I am running this instance on a RHEL 9 server with python 3.11 (base python 3.9, using alias). However after installing airflow, I discovered the pods are running on python 3.8. This version does not exist on my system, so it has to come from the helm chart. I have spent two days scrubbing the internet and have found no information on helm requiring python 3.8. I am installing my python dependencies using a dockerfile which specifies 3.11, but during the build it reverts to python 3.8. I feel like I am at my whit's end, has anyone experienced this issue?
pod python version
airflow@airflow-triggerer-0:/opt/airflow$ python --version Python 3.8.18

OS python versions (both for posterity)
[airflow@_______ ~]$ python --version Python 3.9.18
[airflow@_______ ~]$ source ~/.bashrc
[airflow@_______ ~]$ python --version Python 3.11.5

dockerfile
FROM python:3.11
FROM apache/airflow:2.8.3-python3.11

RUN echo "if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc; fi" >> ~/.bash_profile

COPY requirements.txt . 
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
USER airflow

I feel like I am going crazy, I need another perspective. I have rebuild my cluster dozens of times at this point.
I have attempted to find where helm is created a venv python but have not had any luck.

Helm is written in Go. It shouldn't need / use Python. Airflow, on the other hand, would use Python, regardless of being ran in Kubernetes. (You can run the Docker image without Kubernetes and test the version)

Neither Helm nor Kubernetes directly controls the Python version.  Helm just creates Kubernetes manifests and sends them to the cluster, and Kubernetes will run whatever image: is specified.

I had a similar issue. Using the following helm values overrides appears to have resolved this for me:
# values.yaml

images:
  airflow:
    repository: apache/airflow
    tag: 2.8.3-python3.11  # or choose your preferred tag

(See airflow helm chart parameters reference here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/parameters-ref.html#images)
and then install with
$ helm install $RELEASE_NAME apache-airflow/airflow \
  --namespace $NAMESPACE \
  -f values.yaml

(or equivalent).
Hope this can help!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
